# How to define an optional dependency in a debian package

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies, deb, packaging

I'm working in some Debian packages and at some point I'd like to add optional dependencies, e.g. if `foo-pkg` is marked as to be installed at the same time as `my-pkg` let `foo-pkg` install first and then continue with `my-pkg`, if `foo-pkg` is not available or not marked to be installed just continue.

I could use the `Recommend:` field but as far as my tests has gone it doesn't force `apt-get` to install `foo-pkg` first, also, I don't have control over `foo-pkg`, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want your package to be installed after?  Does your postinst configure your package differently if it finds the other package is installed?  If so then you can use a trigger to cause your package to be reconfigured any time the other package is installed.

Follows some documentation:

- https://sources.debian.org/src/dpkg/1.20.0/doc/triggers.txt
- https://web.archive.org/web/20111022012105/http://www.seanius.net/blog/2009/09/dpkg-triggers-howto/
- https://raphaelhertzog.com/2011/05/30/trying-to-make-dpkg-triggers-more-useful-and-less-painful/

Comment: Indeed, it configures the package differently, I also forgot to mention I don't have control over the other package, right now it can be reconfigured with dpkg-reconfigure once the other package has been installed but it's a two step process.

Comment: @chilicuil, you can use a file trigger on some file in the other package ( such as its main program ) and dpkg will notify your maintainer scripts after the other program is installed or removed.

Comment: that would be great, unfortunatelly I don't have control over the other package

Comment: @chilicuil, you don't need control over the other package.  You register interest in a file in your own package and dpkg takes care of the rest.

Comment: could you point to some example/documentation?

Comment: @chilicuil, http://sources.debian.net/src/dpkg/1.18.22/doc/triggers.txt/